# Adjust the input size in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

It seems that the width of `select` element and `input` element are equal. How can I make it so that `input` element would take much more space and `select` would take less space?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect03">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `col-*` classes in the select and input:

```html
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <div class="input-group mb-3 row">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select col-4" id="inputGroupSelect03">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
        </select>
        <input class="col-8 form-control">
      </div>
```

Comment: @BillPham Glad, it worked. Make sure you add row class in the container. The grid layout of bootstrap is designed around this structure.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add col-* class to your select

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select col-3" id="inputGroupSelect03">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control col">
</div>
```

> `.input-group` has already `.row` style so no need to give .row
>   class. if you give `.row` then it gives negative margin that doesn't
>   need.

Comment: Welcome @BillPham :)

Comment: Why don't we need the add `row` class into the parent element though? As in the other answer, he/she does have `row` class.

Comment: You see if we give row class then it add margin left and right to -15px and in this case we don't need it

Comment: Bootstrap 4 use flex so you also not worry about clearfixing element.

Comment: @BillPham `.input-group` has already `.row` style so no need to give row. in that, if you give row then it gives negative margin that doesn't needed